# Removing the initial + sign from a string if present

Tags: java

I have a method that gets a single string and returns it as either (lets say)

```
s = "+8.7x^2+6x+3"   
//OR
s = "-8.7x^2+6x+3"
```

How do I format this string so that it removes the positive sign if the first term of the string is positive `(s.charAt(0))`, but it doesn't remove the negative sign if the first term is negative?

I want to use `s.subString()` and/or `s.charAt()` if that's possible.

Comment: *"I want to use s.subString() and/or s.charAt() if that's possible."* Okay, what happened when you tried?

Comment: `s = s.substring(1);`

Comment: @Olayinka what is that for?

Comment: @MarounMaroun better a comment than an answer to make the question easily deletable

Comment: When I tried, it would replaced the first character with nothing. I didn't post my original code though because it was incorrect. I have posted the correct answer that @Maroun Maroun gave me below. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

`s.charAt(0)` will give you the first character so you simply need to compare that with `+` and, if it matches, use `substring` to get rid of it.

However, `charAt(0)` has a nasty habit of failing for an empty string so I tend to prefer `startsWith()`:

```
if (s.startsWith("+"))
    s = s.substring(1);
```

Comment: why only in case of -, as it is string so won't it be necessary to get rid of + sign too?

Comment: @Rishi, sorry, had it wrong way around. OP only wants to get rid of leading`+`.

Answer (score 2):

@Maroun posted the perfect answer moments ago but I can't find it anywhere. In case anyone needs this question and answer in the future, here is the answer.

```
if (s.charAt(0) == '+') { 
           s = s.replaceFirst("\\+","");
```

Comment: Once you _know_ the first character is `+`, it's a waste of time using `replaceFirst` - `substring` seems a better way to go. You may as well shorten your code to `s = s.replaceFirst("^\\+","");` :-)

Comment: `replaceFirst` is overkill here

Comment: I thought OP gets the String as `s = +8.7x^2+6x+3`, that's why I suggested using `replaceFirst`, if the String is `+8.7x^2+6x+3`, `substring` is definitely better.

Comment: Unfortunately with this entire java program, you cannot _know_ that it is going to be a positive or a negative as the symbols are just symbols meaning that negative integers are worked out as integers and the "-" is stuck in before it during the runtime of other classes.. I believe 'replaceFirst' to be necessary. I tried the method of just using substring before i posted the question however it would always remove the negative symbol.

Comment: @Lang_lang Once you have checked `s.charAt(0)=='+'`, you don't need to use `replaceFirst`. You can use `substring(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Given we know this is always going to be the first character. You could also use the conditional operator:

```
s = (s.charAt(0) == '+') ? s.substring(1) : s;
```

To test:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "-8.7x^2+6x+3";
    s = (s.charAt(0) == '+') ? s.substring(1) : s;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output is:

```
-8.7x^2+6x+3
```

Whilst if:

```
String s = "+8.7x^2+6x+3";
```

ouput is:

```
8.7x^2+6x+3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah thank you! This is awesome! I tried to use a conditional operator myself but i couldn't get it to work! I was missing the ? symbol in your code. I appreciate the effort! @Loco234